# How to render doctype through Haml's view helpers

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, haml

I can put the following code in a *.html.haml view file:

```
!!!
```

and HAML will render:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

But I cannot find a equivalent HAML view helper method to achieve the same effect.

Comment: What do you mean by “HAML view helper”?

Comment: Is that what you're looking for? http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.HAML_REFERENCE.html#doctype_